# Clear memory when reloading TextView with new text - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, file, memory, memory-leaks

I have a function below that changes the text of a text view by getting the contents of a file stored in the main bundle:

```
func setUpText() {

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: book, ofType: "txt")

    var rawText = ""
    do {
        rawText = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    } catch {
        print("Contents of File could not be retrieved")
    }

    myTextView.text = rawText

}
```

When the user changes the value of book, this function is called and the text view is populated with the new text. Everything works fine, but I've noticed in the Debug Navigator which shows CPU, Memory, Disk, and Network usage information, that Memory keeps going up every time I repopulate the text. How can I clear the memory before changing the text?

Here's how setUpText is called in viewDidLoad:

```
aiv.startAnimating()
myTextView.text = ""
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.setUpText()
    self.aiv.stopAnimating()
    self.aiv.isHidden = true
}
```

I'm also calling setUpText in the function below in the dropdownMenu.didSelectItemAtIndexHandler closure. This is the source of my problem, when I add this, the memory climbs without ever going down as verified through Instrumenting.

```
func createDropdownMenu(title: String, items: [AnyObject]) -> BTNavigationDropdownMenu {

    let dropdownMenu = BTNavigationDropdownMenu(navigationController: self.navigationController,
                                                containerView: self.navigationController!.view,
                                                title: title,
                                                items: items)

    dropdownMenu.didSelectItemAtIndexHandler = { (indexPath: Int) -> () in
        self.chapterIndex = indexPath + 1
        self.setUpText()
    }

    return dropdownMenu

}
```

Comment: Your code looks good and should not leak memory. Do you maybe call it from within a closure?

Comment: In fact, I do call it from within a closure, I just edited the post to show how it's called.

Comment: **this is a real thing!** example:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59020919/294884

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything that would cause a retain cycle...*self* doesn't have a strong reference to the closure, so you're fine there.

You can't 'clear memory', per se, under ARC. It won't allow you to manually deallocate an object (nor do you need to--that's the point). My best guess is that because you're reading a string from disk, which is a relatively slow/expensive operation, (emphasis on 'relatively') the system *might* be caching it at least temporarily. This happens in certain cases such [UIImage imageNamed:].

Is this actually causing a problem for you? Have you instrumented it at all?

Comment: I haven't instrumented it but I think it's a problem because with this memory leak, memory usage is unbounded and a user could theoretically use enough memory to crash the app. I've read elsewhere that using weak or unowned references in closures can solve this problem, do you know how to implement that?

Comment: 1) How do you know you have a leak? You haven't instrumented it. More importantly, what actual problem are you trying to solve here? A small allocation that doesn't instantly disappear when you think it should is not a problem. Let ARC do its thing and don't fret about memory until you really DO have a problem. A problem is something the user will notice--your app crashes, performs sluggishly, whatever. Premature optimization being the root of all evil, and all that...

Comment: 2) You don't have a retain cycle, at least not in the snippets you shared. Retain cycles occur when two objects have strong references to each other. In the case of a closure, it happens when (a) the closure strongly captures 'self', AND (b) 'self' has a strong reference *to the closure*. Part 'b' is not true here...you aren't hanging on to that closure as a property, for example. You are just passing it to a dispatch_async call, fire-and-forget. Again...relax! :D

Comment: Thanks for your comments. You're right, the dispatch_async call was not the problem. I've determined what the problem is though, it's when I call setUpText in another closure that's part of a dropdownMenu. Please see my edited post. Thanks again.